# How this expression leads to the given sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here given is a sequence from [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A008826).

The sequence is triangle of coefficients from fractional iteration of e^x - 1. Few terms are:
1, 1, 3, 1, 13, 18, 1, 50, 205, 180, 1, 201, 1865, 4245, 2700, 1, 875, 16674

The expression of finding the sequence is also given as:
A(n;x) for n-th row satisfies
 A(n;x) = Sum_{k=0..n-1} Stirling_2(n, k)*A(k;x)*x, A(1;x) = 1.

The [tabular](http://oeis.org/A008826/table)  view shows the entries row wise. Stirling_2(n,k) is most probably [stirling numbers of the second type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

I am not able to get how above expression is resulting in the given sequence.
In summation, k begins from 0, but nothing is mentioned about A(0;x). I assumed it to be 0, but still can't get the above values.
Please explain how the first few terms are resulting from the expression.

Comment: What is the connection to computer science (especially functional programming)? Looks like plain math for me.

Comment: @frafl when you tabulate data for large values of n it relates to computer science. And yes sorry fr that functional programming, I was actually looking for functions and just hurried through that part.

Comment: I agree with frafl that this has nothing to do with computer science, rather it's discrete mathematics. But since the question has already been answered here, we might as well leave it be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stirling numbers of the second type satisfy
$$ \newcommand{\stirling}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}\stirling{n}{0} = 0, \qquad (n \neq 0)$$
and so there is no need to define $A(0;x)$, and so the formula seems to work. You can also play with the Mathematica code which can be found in the entry corresponding to the sequence. I am puzzled, however, what is meant by "fractional iteration of $e^x-1$".

The recurrence given is for *generating functions*. Let's rewrite it:
$$
A_1(x) = 1, \qquad A_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \stirling{n}{k} A_k(x) x.
$$
Using a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values) for the Stirling numbers, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
A_1(x) &= 1 \\
A_2(x) &= \stirling{2}{1} A_1(x) x = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot x = x \\
A_3(x) &= \stirling{3}{1} A_1(x) x + \stirling{3}{2} A_2(x) x = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot x + 3 \cdot x \cdot x = x + 3x^2 \\
A_4(x) &= \stirling{4}{1} A_1(x) x + \stirling{4}{2} A_2(x) x + \stirling{4}{3} A_3(x) x \\ &= 1 \cdot 1 \cdot x + 7 \cdot x \cdot x + 6 (x + 3x^2) x  = x + 13x^2 + 18x^3
\end{align*}
$$
and so on. The numbers in the table are $a(n,k) = A_n(x)|_{x^k}$ :
$$
\begin{align*}
a(2,1) &= 1, \\
a(3,1) &= 1, \\
a(3,2) &= 3, \\
a(4,1) &= 1, \\
a(4,2) &= 13, \\
a(4,3) &= 18,
\end{align*}
$$

If you prefer an actual recurrence on the coefficients, here is what you get:
$$
\begin{align*}
a(n,l) = \begin{cases} 1 & l = 1, \\ \sum_{k=l}^{n-1} \stirling{n}{k} a(k,l-1) & l > 1. \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: even for k>n
$$ \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{k} = 0$$
right?

Comment: and yes the mathematica code, how do we get the entry 13 in there? can you explain manually?

Comment: The recurrence is for generating functions. I explain how to use it, and also give a recurrence for the actual coefficients.

Comment: you are awesome.!!